# Android Simple application development question

Tags: android

New to the group and new to Android development. At our site we are starting to look into Android application development and as I have the most programming background here I have been tasked with learning to develop on Android.

My programming background includes RPG and CL, (AS/400), Pick DataBasic, Paradox ObjectPal, Basic in a variety of flavors, (of course), a little C and C++, Comal, a little dabbling in Visual Basic and AutoIt scripting language. I have worked a lot in Oracle, Informix and some MS-SQL.

I have installed and configured Eclipse and the Android SDK.

I have an idea for what I think would be a fairly simple application to get my feet wet as it were.

We have a variety of documentation that is in PDF and Epub.

I would like to create an application where the APK contains all the specified documentation for a given application with the following criteria. When the user installs the APK file it would do the following:

1. Create a folder on the SD card called SystemDocs,
2. Create a subfolder under System Docs for the a given system say Accounting for example
3. Create two subfolders under accounting one for PDF files and one for Epub documents
4. Check to ensure that the user has a suitable application installed for reading PDF and Epub documents and if not find it on the Android Market and ask the user to install it.
5. Copy the Epub and PDF documents to their respective folders
6. Exit

Based on the above I was looking for some recommendations as to where to go from here. I am the type that likes to just dive in and start trying to write something useful as opposed to the

10 For x = 1 to 10
20 Print “My First Basic Program”
30 Next X 
40 End

Kind of thing. Any thoughts, advice, recommendations, or example code would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Gordon

Comment: maybe read there about data storage : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest visiting the following link:
http://developer.android.com/resources/index.html

One nice thing about a few of the tutorials, is that they give you base code to start with, and have you add in extra information.  This is nice because it cuts out some of the repetitiveness, yet if you wanted you could still type it all yourself.

After that if you have questions, stackoverflow is a great place to get advice on code or any troubles you may have.

Other than that, searching google for tutorials (or blogs that main contain tutorials,) and I'd even recommend youtube.  Good luck with your ventures!